# php opens gedit now rather than firefox

Tags: php

I have apache installed and therefore webserver is running.

I used to double click on the php files and they open up in ff by default and executes the codes. Just now, when I double click on them, they open in gedit and they also do not run in firefox. If I open them in firefox, it just displays the raw code.

Now to get them run, I need to enter the url in the browser to obtain the result.

So I'm curious about how this happened.

Comment: That's a natural behavior, I have no clue how is it possible that you could open it with firefox before. You sure they weren't HTML?

Comment: It's a program default in your OS. Your OS will assign programs to specific file types. You don't mention the OS you're using, but look into how to change program defaults.

Comment: @aynber: Since he's using gedit, I'd assume Linux (probably Ubuntu).

Comment: @RocketHazmat I figured that as well, but I figured there might be variants that run under Windows/Cygwin and Mac OS, so I didn't want to assume.

Comment: yes, I run on linux. But how come the php files used to be read as html files? And now they aren't?

Comment: @aynber: I like to assume :P

Answer (score 2):

Firefox, the web browser, will not run/interpret your PHP scripts - they are run/interpreted by an interpreter that runs somewhere.  Typically, when you've opened up your PHP scripts in the past, it is likely that you've accessed a URL for them on your local system via firefox (such as a url like `http://localhost/~user/file.php`) .  When you did this, your server ran the PHP and displayed the results.

When you double click on the file, it opens it for editing (in your case, gedit is used to edit PHP files)

If you have browser history enabled, you might find it useful to go through your history and look for the URL you used previously to access PHP through the server on your system.  URL's that start with 'file://' are simply reading the contents of the file, not interpreting them.

Comment: They used to open in file:///path.., and they ran! I presume it was run and also interpreted as html for some strange reason. Any guesses?

Comment: It might be that you only saw the HTML that was in them - so they looked as if they were producing useful output.  PHP code embedded in HTML is typically wrapped in <?php > or <?= > tags, and would therefore not render in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Thats supposed to happen, you can't run php code by double clicking on it, you need to set up the PHP and Apache server and run it on `http://localhost/`

Check out this: http://www.wampserver.com/en/